# Validating Javascript Console Errors and Warnings with Java, Selenium, and Cucumber

Tags: javascript, java, selenium-webdriver, cucumber

I am working on automating some tests using Cucumber with Java and Selenium WebDriver. I have a step defined to check the browser console for any errors or warnings after the application loads. The step is defined as follows:

```
@Then("he checks if there are no console errors or warnings")
public void checkConsoleForErrorsAndWarnings() {
    LogEntries logEntries = SelectorHelper.getDriver().manage().logs().get(LogType.BROWSER);
    for (LogEntry entry : logEntries) {
        String message = entry.getMessage();
        assertFalse(message.contains("ERROR"), () -> "Console error found: " + message);
        assertFalse(message.contains("WARN"), () -> "Console warning found: " + message);
    }
}
```

The problem I am facing is that even if there are warnings in the console, this step passes without any assertion failure. I suspect that the message.contains("WARN") condition is not working as expected, or perhaps the log entries are not being captured correctly.

I am looking for alternative approaches to solve this issue. Does anyone have suggestions on how to modify this step or a different method to accurately capture and assert any console errors or warnings? Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.